# Save checkbox values from csv django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have CSV file in this formate [image: CSV file image]

I can get data into this field dynamically. How Can I save this data into database so that I can show easily as form of check boxes .And save data into model using this csv.

**My model is something like this**

```
restaurant = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ArticleName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    Pickuptax = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=100)   //As I can't assign static choice fields here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a model for ingredient and a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Create an Ingredient model like this:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Then change your ingredient field to:

```
Ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
```

Then you can add ingredients to an article like this:

```
def add_ingredient(article, name):
    ingredient = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
    article.Ingredients.add(ingredient)
    article.save()
```

By the way, you should not use uppercase names for member variables, so instead of `ArticleName`, use `article_name`. Uppercase naming is for classes only

Comment: thanks for good suggestion. Can you tell aswell how I can save this from csv ? as its manytomany relation now and from csv how I will get this.

Comment: That depends on how you import your CSV, do you use some sort of library for this?

Comment: No I am using method mentioned in this  https://www.pythoncircle.com/post/30/how-to-upload-and-process-the-csv-file-in-django/     but I am having issue in this field now